# How to catch specific ValidationError in Django form

Tags: python, django

I have a django form in which the user can submit a form to create a new item. There are a few error conditions which return different JsonResponses. I'm wondering if I can catch a specific validation error without checking the string contents of the error.

The two errors I am checking for are either if the fields are not all filled out, or if the item name has an invalid length (there's a max of 25 characters).

To better explain, here is a snippet of my code:

```
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({item: item.to_json()})
        else:
            if "has at most" in str(form.errors):
                return JsonResponse({
                    "error": "Invalid Length",
                    "message": "Ensure the category name is within the given length"
                })
            else:
                return JsonResponse({
                    "error": "Invalid",
                    "message": "Please fill out all of the fields."
                })
```

This code does currently work, but obviously I would like to avoid this hack where I am checking the contents of the error in the string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: welcom to SO. what do you want to do after validation next? if you want to just throw an error, you can use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators). [here is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) django official guide on field validation.